# How to access odata that produced by Nav webservice into html layout using PHP

Tags: php, odata, navision

I try to get odata produced by a navision webservice. When I directly access the url given using chrome browser, the page asks for user name and password and then chrome shows xml data as expected.

But when i use a PHP script, it always returns "1".

My code looks like this:

```
$url = 'http://103.7.1.182:14048/DynamicsNAV71-6/OData/Company(\'Unit%20G%205\')/Item_Master_on_hand_no_Desc';
$login = 'Gem-gae\senzo1:Bsbsenzo2018';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
      'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                                                                                
      'Content-Length: ' . strlen(1))                                                                       
  );
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Is there any mistakes with that code ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Why `'Content-Length: ' . strlen(1))` ? You may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22564260/1911019

Comment: Thanks Alberto, because there's no data post sent needed exept username and password. May you can access that web service url given? thanks again Alberto...

Comment: Shouldn’t you use GET instead of POST?

Answer (score 1):

There's no mistake on your code, it successfully connects to the external server via cURL and retrieves the data.
The value in $output (if you do a var_dump) is `true` (that's why you see `1` if you echo it).

Said that, the issue is on the server you are contacting (103.7.1.182:14048). 
You probably need to send some data or something, I can't tell you exactly what because I don't know what is in that server.
To send data, you can add a `curl_setopt` line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

Where $data is an array.